How to disable pushing, merging and pulling into master while pipeline is running in Gitlab?
I'm running a pipeline every day. This pipeline basically pushes my origin/master into several remote branches. Since there are many remote branches (approx. 70) this could take around 1.5 hours including test phase. During this deploy pipeline it is possible to push into origin/master. So it could happen that my tests won't run for a change, but it will still be pushed to the remote branches. Is there a way for me to disable any changes to origin/master while the deploy pipeline is running?
I'm thinking of introducing a new stage into my pipeline that locks the branch and an other stage that unlocks the branch after the deploy has finished. Is this a manageble solutions? Should I look elsewhere? How could this be achieved?

You did not show any script here, so I might misinterpret the question. But if your pipelines are running in GitLab CI, the job already have a specific commit. If using the default git fetch operation in jobs, the code will be at that commit. If you are using your own git commands there, just use e.g. git checkout $CI_COMMIT_SHA.
Then blocking other pushes to master would then be unnecessary/irrelevant (they are different commits).
I have suggested a solution to your question below, but I suspect altering the pipeline logic to stick to a given commit would serve you better.

You can probably use the GitLab API to freeze the master branch by using the GitLab API, something like:
export PROJECT_ID=5
export ACCESS_TOKEN=<your_access_token>

# Protect master:
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/protected_branches?name=master&push_access_level=0&merge_access_level=0&unprotect_access_level=40"

# Unprotect master:
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/protected_branches?name=master&push_access_level=40&merge_access_level=40&unprotect_access_level=40"

The access level numbers are:
0  => No access
30 => Developer access
40 => Maintainer access (used in unprotect-curl in my above suggestion, just an example)
60 => Admin access


One approach is to create a deployment flag in your CI/CD pipeline that prevents pushing to master until the deploy finishes. This can be done using a  file that both your CI/CD system and Git hooks can access.
Create a Deployment Flag: Before the pipeline starts, set a deployment flag, which can be a file that a deployment is in progress.
Check Flag During Push: Use a Git pre-push hook that checks for the flag (file) before allowing a push to master.
Example in a pre-push hook:
# Check if deployment flag exists
if [ -f /path/to/deployment_in_progress ]; then
  echo "Deployment is in progress. Please wait."
  exit 1
fi

Remove Flag After Deployment: Once the deployment completes successfully, remove the flag to allow further changes to master.
